# For Loops with Scrapy

Tags: for-loop, web-scraping, scrapy

Hey y'all I have been trying to learn scrapy, and am working on my first project right now. I have written this code to try to scrape NFL player news from http://www.rotoworld.com/playernews/nfl/football/?rw=1. I tried to set up a loop to get each container from the site, but when I run the code it isn't scraping anything. The code runs fine, even pus out a csv file when I ask it too. It just isn't scraping what I think I am telling it to scrape. Any help would be great! Thanks

```
import scrapy
from Roto_Player_News.items import NFLNews

class Roto_News_Spider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name="PlayerNews2"
    allowed_domains = ["rotoworld.com"]
    start_urls = ('http://www.rotoworld.com/playernews/nfl/football/',)

    def parse(self,response):

        containers= response.xpath('//*[@id="cp1_pnlNews"]/div/div[2]')

        def parse(self, response):

            for container in containers:
                def parse(self, response):           
                    item=NFLNews()
                    item['player']= response.xpath('//div[@class="pb"][1]/div[@id="cp1_ctl00_rptBlurbs_floatingcontainer_0"]/div[@class="report"]/text()')
                    item['headline'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="pb"][1]/div[@id="cp1_ctl00_rptBlurbs_floatingcontainer_0"]/div[@class="report"]/p/text()').extract()
                    item['info'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="pb"][1]/div[@id="cp1_ctl00_rptBlurbs_floatingcontainer_0"]/div[@class="impact"]/text()').extract()
                    item['date'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="pb"][1]/div[@id="cp1_ctl00_rptBlurbs_floatingcontainer_0"]/div[@class="info"]/div[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
                    item['source'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="pb"][1]/div[@id="cp1_ctl00_rptBlurbs_floatingcontainer_0"]/div[@class="info"]/div[@class="source"]/a/text()').extract()

                    yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your defined xpaths do not look good. Try this instead. It should fetch you the content you wish to scrape. Just do the copy and paste.

```
import scrapy

class Roto_News_Spider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "PlayerNews2"

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.rotoworld.com/playernews/nfl/football/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.xpath("//div[@class='pb']"):
            player = item.xpath(".//div[@class='player']/a/text()").extract_first()
            report = item.xpath(".//div[@class='report']/p/text()").extract_first()
            date = item.xpath(".//div[@class='date']/text()").extract_first()
            impact = item.xpath(".//div[@class='impact']/text()").extract_first().strip()
            source = item.xpath(".//div[@class='source']/a/text()").extract_first()
            yield {"Player": player,"Report":report,"Date":date,"Impact":impact,"Source":source}
```

Comment: Thank you. If I want to also get team and position, what should I do? The player's name is nicely embedded in that a tag, but how do you play around with text in that div.class="player"?

Comment: Try this two: `idk1 = item.xpath(".//div[@class='player']/text()").extract()[0].strip()` and `idk2 = item.xpath(".//div[@class='player']/a/text()").extract()[1].strip()`. I suppose this is what you meant.

Comment: cool. At a theoretical level what are the arrays of [0] and [1] asking for? The second path works and gives me the team. The position still doesn't. Is there a way to ask for the text between "-"? I was able to do that when using BeautifulSoup but am confused how to do that with xpath and scrapy. Thanks for all the help man!

Comment: If this are `T`,`DL`,`DB` what you meant by position then they are rightly coming through at my end.

Comment: sorry you are right. I had a typo. are you also getting the "-"?

Comment: To kick that out try this `item.xpath(".//div[@class='player']/text()").extract()[0].replace("-","").strip()`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much man. You have done more than enough, so please don't feel like you need to do this, but do you mind explaining the array part?

Comment: I'll try to have a look tomorrow.